# How to use the IndexMut trait in rust correctly?

Tags: rust, traits

I recently played around with rust and tried to implement indexing for a Point struct, so that `some_point[2]` would give me the z coordinate.

But I was not able to get the code below to compile. What am I missing?

```
struct Point {
  x: int,
  y: int,
  z: int
}

impl IndexMut<uint, int> for Point {
  fn index_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, index: &uint) -> &'a mut int {
    & mut match *index {
      0 => self.x,
      1 => self.y,
      2 => self.z,
      _ => 0 //TODO: add proper error handling
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
[me@localhost rust]$ rustc blabla.rs && ./blabla
blabla.rs:25:11: 30:6 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
blabla.rs:25     & mut match *index {
blabla.rs:26       0 => self.x,
blabla.rs:27       1 => self.y,
blabla.rs:28       2 => self.z,
blabla.rs:29       _ => 0
blabla.rs:30     }
blabla.rs:24:63: 31:4 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 24:62...
blabla.rs:24   fn index_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, index: &uint) -> &'a mut int {
blabla.rs:25     & mut match *index {
blabla.rs:26       0 => self.x,
blabla.rs:27       1 => self.y,
blabla.rs:28       2 => self.z,
blabla.rs:29       _ => 0
             ...
blabla.rs:24:63: 31:4 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 24:62
blabla.rs:24   fn index_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, index: &uint) -> &'a mut int {
blabla.rs:25     & mut match *index {
blabla.rs:26       0 => self.x,
blabla.rs:27       1 => self.y,
blabla.rs:28       2 => self.z,
blabla.rs:29       _ => 0
             ...
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I'm sorry stackoverflow forced me to format the error message as code. I hope it's still readable enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your match block copies self.x etc. and then the function attempts to return a mutable reference to it (at least that's my interpretation). Try this instead

```
match *index {
  0 => & mut self.x,
  1 => & mut self.y,
  2 => & mut self.z,
  _ => fail!("")
}
```